# HTML text not fitting in div

Tags: html, css

So bascially, I have a div inside another div. The inner div is supposed to have width 100px (outer div has width 430px), with text overflow in x direction automatically broken into the next line, and in the y direction scrollable.

Here's my HTML code

```
<div>
   <div class="text">
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
      <p>this is a long-ass line that is supposed to cause overflow</p>
   </div>
<div>
```

Then my CSS:

```
/* Actual card content stuff */
.text {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 5px;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.text::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE and Edge */
.text {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

It ended up looking like this, which is nowhere near what I expected:
[image: The unexpected display]

The div is apparently way wider and way shorter than expected. Note that, the area with the sunflower as a background is the outer div, and the inner div is supposed to wrap the text. I am very confused why this is happening. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The code you have here does not produce the output in your screenshot (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xcemk847/)), so would you be able to produce a [mcve]?

Comment: Hmmmm... Ok, sorry the reason why I didn't put the whole code is, the entire thing is pretty complicated. I will can try to figure out a minimum point in my code that will produce this error. Sorry for inconveniences, I'll go ahead and do it right now

Comment: Ooh! I figured out the problem. The parent div had its paragraphs positioned absolutely, therefore causing the problem. Removing that line solved the problem. Thanks for your help!